# Decode in SQL (Please help understand this code)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
decode(trim(emp.gsr_country_code), 
                           '484',
                           lpad(trim(emp.gsr_center6), 5, '0'),
                           decode(length(trim(emp.gsr_center6)),
                                  7,
                                  substr(trim(emp.gsr_center6), 3, 5),
                                  trim(emp.gsr_center6)))
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you *reformat* it so that you actually see what's compared to what, then it looks like this (unfortunately, you'll now have to scroll right):

```
decode(trim(emp.gsr_country_code), '484', lpad(trim(emp.gsr_center6), 5, '0'),
                                          decode(length(trim(emp.gsr_center6)), 7, substr(trim(emp.gsr_center6), 3, 5),
                                                                                   trim(emp.gsr_center6)
                                                )
      )
```

So, what does it do?

- `trim` removes any spaces from `emp.gsr_country_code` and compares it with `'484'`

  - if trimmed `gsr_country_code` equals `'484'`, then function (`decode`, right?) returns trimmed `emp.gsr_center6` which is left-padded with zeros up to 5 characters in length
  - if it isn't equal to `'484'`, then it goes to another `decode` (in line #2)
- it checks whether length of trimmed `emp.gsr_center6` is equal to `7`

  - if so, it returns `5` characters from trimmed `emp.gsr_center6`, starting at character #3
  - if not, it returns trimmed `emp.gsr_center6`

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for looking it up its really helpful